Volkswagen Transporter T5 1.9 tdi
I had turbo failure, white smoke coming out like i was a train. I stopped the van 1 minute later. Then i had turbo replaced with a reconditioned one. Once i replaced it, smoke was still coming out almost in the same manner, but it was because the exhaust was full of oil from previous turbo failure. The engine turned on easily and smooth, i drove it like 3-4 miles and after that it cut power and didn't start again even after replacing battery

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question?

A failed turbo is typically a source of blue smoke, not white smoke, in a VW 1.9 TDI. White smoke is most commonly from the EGR cooler leaking antifreeze into the intake air, or sometimes from an injector that is stuck open. A failed MAF sensor can also make white smoke from too much fuel. Please scan the engine for codes, edit your question to add a complete list of codes, state the vehicle or engine year and ask us an actual question as Paulster2 requests, so that we can help you.

It's 2008 1.9 tdi, it was definetly turbo failure since i've found part of the turbo inside the exhaust. Once i replaced the turbo, the van started well, drove almost well but there was some lag since exhaust was still full of oil and it was still smoking bad.  After it gets hot, the engine lose power and turn off then it's impossible to turn it on again while it's hot. I tried again today and same thing happened, turned on easy while cold then started losing power after it got hot enough

@Mihai  Please scan the engine for codes, edit your question to add a complete list of codes, and ask us an actual question as Paulster2 requests, so that we can help you.
